# single datasource for muiltiple mutiselect dropdown in angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to use Single Array as a Data-Source for Mutiple DropDown element(will be dynamic generated based on another ArrayList) with muti-select and condition begin when any item/'s get selected in any of the DDL, then it should be removed or disabled in the remaining DDL.

PS: I'm new to front end development and using Angular1.5 with TypeScript.

Ex: 
DS for Select Option:  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

I kind of facing problem when we are deselecting any item from the any of the DDL, since the deselected values needs to be pushed based to Available Values Array for the remaining DDL.

Comment: Show some code or fiddle would be great to get help quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create an array of objects like [{value:1, disabled:false}, .....]
and work with the disable property.

should be something like:

```
<md-select ng-repeat="item in myItems">
<md-option
... ng-click="item.disabled = !item.disabled"></md-option>
```